# Stuck on "Collecting BeautifulSoup"

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I downgraded my Python version to 2.7 because the program I'm using required Python 2.7 in order to run but after running the command `pip install BeautifulSoup` it's stuck saying "Collecting BeautifulSoup" and it's been saying that for an hour now... How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried killing the process and running it again?

Comment: @jwodder yes I have

Comment: Try: `pip install beautifulsoup4`